# Xcode 7, duplicate identical addresses for weak pointers

Tags: swift, var, xcode7, weak

I am a little confused by something I am seeing in Xcode 7, the 3 colors below all have a separate address as you would expect, but the weak colors all have the same address. I understand that the weak colors are optionals so weak_R and color_R have different addresses, but I can't quite work out why all 3 weaks display the same address.

Does this seem right, and if it is can someone explain what I am seeing? If not I am guessing its a bug.

## CODE

```
    var color_R = SKColor.redColor()
    var color_G = SKColor.greenColor()
    var color_B = SKColor.blueColor()
    weak var weak_R = color_R
    weak var weak_G = color_G
    weak var weak_B = color_B
```

## DEBUG

[image]

Comment: I think it's an XCode bug: typing `p weak_R` at the lldb prompt will print a less surprising address.

Comment: File a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Much appreciated, for a minute I was thinking that I was missing something fundamental :) your suggestion of p weak_R, p weak_G do indeed print different addresses,  i had been trying po rather than p. So it is indeed a bug (at least as far as the UI goes) Thanks again for confirming Sir.